# empty form appears to hang when loading

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, interop

any help with this would be gratefully received.

I have a Windows Forms project in C#. This, when a button is pressed opens a new Outlook email via interop. When the email has been sent and added to the sent items folder, the Windows Forms project then opens a single form which contains a single panel currently.

My problem is that everything seems to run fine, I use Marshalling to sever the links with the interop instance of Outlook all other methods seem to run as normal in the Windows Forms project, but the form that is opened (called zoom) just shows the Spinning Wheel waiting symbol.

When I break on the code to see what it's doing, it appears to be doing nothing.  This is driving me nuts. Can anyone suggest why the form (Zoom) that is launched after the interop facility has done its stuff and apparently been disposed appears to hang.

It does appear to me somehow to be connected to the Interop instance but I can't see how.

Comment: Please post the code snippets that open your form and interact with the outlook form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I remember interop objects should be disposed.

Try [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10078376/how-to-dispose-of-a-com-interop-object.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I am doing the Marshalling but it still hangs, everything else works okay just loading this one form, well any form basically after the interop.

Comment: Try to put breakpoints in the code and see where it hangs up exactly in your application, without the code I can't say more...

Comment: I've put break points in and all the code appears to be running with no stops. The actual usage of the form is as an empty form with one panel which will be loaded with a Usercontrol at form launch. I've disabled this code in case that was causing the hanging but this is not the case. I marshall the Outlook.Application, Outlook.Namespace and Outlook.MailItem object after usage and then set to null for good measure. The form (which doesn't use interop) loads but cannot maintain focus and when the mouse passes over it, just presents the spinning wait wheel.